# Downloading All Files from SFTP folder to local folder with Date using Python

Tags: python, sftp

I am using the following code to download files,

```
def download_dir(remote_dir, local_dir):
     import os
     os.path.exists(local_dir) or os.makedirs(local_dir)
     dir_items = sftp.listdir_attr(remote_dir)
     for item in dir_items:
        # assuming the local system is Windows and the remote system is 

        # os.path.join won't help here, so construct remote_path manually
        remote_path = remote_dir + '/' + item.filename         
        local_path = os.path.join(local_dir, item.filename)
        if S_ISDIR(item.st_mode):
            download_dir(remote_path, local_path)
        else:
            sftp.get(remote_path, local_path)


download_dir("/home","C:\\Users\\ShareM\\Desktop")
```

How can I download it to a folder with DateStamp? For example, if I download today, the folder it downloads to should be named 07/09/2018.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `datetime` module with `os`

**Ex:**

```
import os
import datetime


local_dir = "C:\\Users\\ShareM\\Desktop"
folderName = os.path.join(local_dir, datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%d-%m-%Y"))    #Create Folder with todays date
os.path.exists(folderName) or os.makedirs(folderName)
```